# Can not get Shopify online access token

Tags: shopify, koa, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am using [`@shopify/koa-shopify-auth`](https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/tree/master/packages/koa-shopify-auth#shopifykoa-shopify-auth) and need to implement online access mode authorization flow, I set accessMode to online but still get offline access token which does not contain associated_user data described in Shopify [docs](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth#step-3-confirm-installation)

[image: screenshot]

Please, correct me If I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I found out that the problem was in `@shopify/koa-shopify-auth`. it just did not put the data to session. [This](https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/pull/1542) is the pull request for the fix.